# mysql query need to be optimized

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which give result like

```
id | productid | userid | coinsid
1  | 2         | 2      |  5     
3  | 2         | 2      |  6      
4  | 2         | 3      |  7
5  | 2         | 4      |  8
6  | 2         | 3      |  9
```

This is result for specific `productid`. Now i have to update the balance in `user table` by adding $1 to all the users in above result, but if `userid` is twice, i need to add $1 twice to the balance of that specific user. So in the above case $1 twice added to `userid=2` balance and `userid=3` balance.

The simple way is to count records for every distinct `userid` and run queries as many time as we have users in `foreach` loop. But i am looking for some optimize way. Please suggest any. Thanks

Comment: group the results of the query by userID and sum coinsID add a column for count of userID multiply the count of userID by your $1 and update the coinsId with that new value.

Comment: @AliBZ, Yes 'balance' is column name in user table. Where i have to update the balance.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I missed that part.

Comment: Here I am trying to figure out where the freak the `$1` variable is coming from, and it finally dawns on me, Oh dear Lord, I've been programing too long. A dollar sign doesn't mean "dollars" to me anymore, I always see it as the beginning of shell script variable, a Perl scalar, or PHP variable, ... and never as money.

Comment: @spencer7593, when it comes to 'balance', $ is no more for variable :)

Comment: i figured it out. i was just surprised at how dense i was. the query in my answer should be working. (i'm setting up the testcase now)

Comment: I just replied to your answer, update me on that ;) Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach:

```
UPDATE user_table u
  JOIN ( SELECT q.userid
              , SUM(1.00) AS deposit
           FROM (
                  -- original OP query goes here
                ) q
          GROUP BY q.userid
       ) r
    ON r.userid = u.userid 
   SET u.balance = u.balance + r.deposit
```

We use the original OP query that returns the resultset displayed, and make that an inline view (aliased in the query above as **q**).

From that, we query a distinct list of userid, and the number of times that userid appears in the resultset. That gives us the username and a deposit amount (1 dollar for each time the userid appears) (some databases might want us to specify the value as 1.0 rather than 1, to make sure it was decimal. I think the SUM is more representative of what we are trying to accomplish.)

We join that inline view (**r**) to the user table, and add the deposit amount to the current balance, for that user (assuming the balance is stored as decimal dollars (1.00 = one dollar)

---

To testing, convert the `UPDATE` into a `SELECT` statement:

- remove the "`SET`" clause
- add an "`ORDER BY`" clause (optional) to make the results determinate
- remove the "`UPDATE`" keyword and replace it

with:

```
 SELECT r.userid
      , r.deposit
      , u.balance             AS old_balance
      , u.balance + r.deposit AS new_balance
      , u.userid
   FROM
```

---

Full select:

```
 SELECT r.userid
      , r.deposit
      , u.balance             AS old_balance
      , u.balance + r.deposit AS new_balance
      , u.userid
   FROM user_table u
  JOIN ( SELECT q.userid
              , SUM(1.00) AS deposit
           FROM (
                  -- original OP query goes here
                ) q
          GROUP BY q.userid
       ) r
    ON r.userid = u.userid
```

**NOTE** There is no WHERE clause, the JOIN predicates (in the ON clause) is what determines which rows are selected/affected in the user table.

Comment: (previously missing the join criteria... DOH!  fixed.

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried it, and it updated balance for me but unfortunately updated balance for all users, Do we need where clause at the end of update query?

Comment: Worked perfectly now. Let me try on multiple users :)

Comment: @M Shahzad Khan: I think you may have gotten a bad version from the  first cut; the `ON` clause was missing. (My bad. But fixed.) That's why we test, to find our mistakes.

Comment: i have it on local database, so no worries, tried it with update and works like a charm. you rocks!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no duplicate user ids in your balance table, maybe something like this would work:

```
update balance_table set balance_table.balance = (select count(*) from users_table where users_table.user_id = balance_table.user_id) * 1;
```

I haven't tried this query against a mysql database as I am more familiar with plsql, but wouldn't something like this work ?

Comment: The * 1 in this case is because you want to add 1$ per user occurence, but could be changed to any amount.

Comment: Not duplicate but multiple userid's, so it won't work i think.

Answer (score 1):

The correlated subquery in the other answer will work, but an INNER JOIN will usually be more efficient. Try something like this; you'll of course need to supply the table and column names.

```
UPDATE myTable
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT userid, count(*) AS AmountToAdd
  FROM users
  GROUP BY userid
) UserCounts ON myTable.userid = UserCounts.userid
SET balance = balance + UserCounts.AmountToAdd
```

Comment: This is a workable approach. But the inline view in this query is  `FROM users`, but OP indicated that the list of users was the result of a query (the actual text of the query wasn't given.) So OP would need to replace `FROM users` with `FROM ( SELECT /*original query*/ ) alias`. Whenever there is more than one table referenced in a query, best practice is to qualify ALL column references.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*), userid from yourTable group by userid
```

If I do understand your question.